# vb.net - control my windowsform application ALSO via web

Tags: vb.net, webforms

I should like to control my old vb.net application also via web.

I should like to duplicate few labels/texts and few buttons/checkbox to control some parameters, simply connecting with a browser to a web page. (Not with Ultravnc or similar)
So, Adding a web interface at the existing project.

I'm note able to find the method to follow.
Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: searching around I have found the possibility to host locally a WCF service,
could be an easier solution, without to rewrite all my old code?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create a VB.net web project.

You'll need to create a new web project for that.  You should also [factor out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) any business logic into a separate assembly so it can be used by both the winforms and web application.

Answer (score 0):

You can make connection between your desktop application and web application with [this code.](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/Uploadfile/mahesh/DownloadWebPage04252005073432AM/DownloadWebPage.aspx)